# Splitting a string into integers using istringstream in C++

Tags: c++, stl, istringstream

I'm trying to use `istringstream` to split a simple string into a series of integers:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string s = "1 2 3"; 
    istringstream iss(s);   

    while (iss)
    {
        int n;
        iss >> n;
        cout << "* " << n << endl;
    } 
}
```

And i get:

```
* 1
* 2
* 3
* 3
```

Why is the last element always coming out twice? How to fix it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's coming out twice because your looping is wrong, as explained (indirectly) at http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5 (`while (iss)` is not dissimilar from `while (iss.eof())` in this scenario).

Specifically, on the third loop iteration, `iss >> n` succeeds and gets your `3`, and leaves the stream in a good state. The loop then runs a fourth time due to this good state, and it's not until the next (fourth) `iss >> n` subsequently fails that the loop condition is broken. But before that fourth iteration ends, you still output `n`... a fourth time.

Try:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "1 2 3"; 
    istringstream iss(s);   
    int n;

    while (iss >> n) {
        cout << "* " << n << endl;
    } 
}
```

Comment: how can we do this in for() loop?

Comment: @SumitKandoi: What do you mean? Why would you?

Comment: actually, i was tried it in while() loop. i was thinking can we do this in for() loop also

Comment: @SumitKandoi: Sure. But why? `for (int n; iss >> n; ) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:
iss : 1 2 3
**Iteration 1**
iss : 1 2 3 (Initially) 
n=1
iss : 2 3
//* 1 is printed
**Iteration 2:**
iss : 2 3 (Initially) 
n=2
iss : 3
//* 2 is printed
**Iteration 3**
iss : 3
n=3
iss : ''
 
**Iteration 4**
iss : ''
n not changed//Flag set for **eof** of iss as no further input from stream
iss : ''

And as rightly mentioned by the above post while (iss) is not dissimilar from while (iss.eof()).
Internally, the function(istream::operator>>) accesses the input sequence by first constructing a [sentry](http://www.cplusplus.com/istream%3a%3asentry) object (with noskipws set to false[This means that space is separator and your list will be 1,2,3]). Then (if [good](http://www.cplusplus.com/ios%3a%3agood)[here eof not reached]), it calls [num_get::get](http://www.cplusplus.com/num_get%3a%3aget) [Get the next integer] to perform both the extraction and the parsing operations, adjusting the stream's internal state flags accordingly. Finally, it destroys the sentry object before returning.

Refer : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

Answer (score 0):

The common case is to split into a vector directly using an iterator, avoiding the messy `while` loop and EOF gotchas entirely (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5168710/6243352) which elaborates nicely on why OP's code doesn't work):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string s = "1 2 3"; 
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    const std::vector<int> values{std::istream_iterator<int>(iss),
                                  std::istream_iterator<int>()};

    for (const int n : values) {
        std::cout << n << "\n";
    }
}
```